# I want to use the reserved word in template group

Tags: templates

i am using ee for the first time, and i try to make a web design explanatory website, but I have a problem that the word 'css' cannot be used for template group name because it is a reserved word.
I tried /CSS/ but it works only when the address is typed as .com/CSS/ ~
I want to use css instead of CSS.
How can I do?

Comment: As has been said, the solution is to use a different name for your template group. But given that it's a pretty straightforward fix I'm wondering if there is something stopping you from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Lol, use the word stylesheet or styles. Why are you trying to break all of the eggs in the carton? You'll run into a lot of roadblocks going the route you want to...

Also, at the end of the day, you are going to **not** want to do all your stylesheet editing, or any template editing, in your browser. You should use an ftp client and your preferred editor, saving templates as files. I would suggest getting your development tool-chain in order now, before you go down the rabbit hole.

**Edit**

To be clear, you can't do what you want. It would require insane core EE modification. Pick a different name for that group, or use your assets/css folder and edit them with a tool-chain solution.